# Xcode Storyboard in team git environment opens with un-added modifications

Tags: ios, xcode, git, storyboard

I'm working on an iOS app in a team git environment. My latest push contained some modifications that I didn't add, and we tracked the cause down to what seems to be a known problem with Xcode, git, and multiple developers. Whenever I pull, or git reset, to/from a point before the change, everything is fine. But if I open a Storyboard (without making any changes), all of the UITableViewCells in the Storyboard are changed by Xcode. The changes look like this, in XML:

```
<rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="72" width="600" height="44"/>
```

becomes

```
<rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="72" width="600" height="44.5"/>
```

Also, the systemVersion attribute is changed, which is normal, but possibly related.

These changes don't affect the layout in any way, but we need a solution that doesn't affect the code in unexpected ways. I've seen this bug reported in numerous places on the internet, but nobody seems to have come up with a consistent solution. I've tried the following:

Reinstalling Xcode
Updating OS X, Xcode, simulators.
Checking out to a different branch (the problem is still there)
Checking out to an old branch (the problem is still there)
Cloning a new repo (the problem is still there)
Downloading the project (this fixes the problem, but...), then setting our github as the remote, tracking a remote branch, then switching to the tracking branch (problem arises again, here)
Altering the Storyboard as source code, then viewing as IB (the problem is still there)
Altering the Storyboard as source code in a text editor, then viewing as IB (the problem is still there)

Can anybody explain what is going on, in terms more specific than "Changing system settings can cause changes in Xcode"? And any ideas for fixes would be appreciated.

Comment: this is nothing to with Git. Its just Xcode modifies it every time you open storyboard or xib. Best practise which I follow is before taking the pull I check storyboard and xibs content in Source Control -> Commit and incase if no changes been made my be I just discard them and then take a pull and finally push my changes

Comment: @aman.sood: Thanks for the reply. This must have SOMETHING to do with git, because if I simply download the project from the remote repo, I don't see the behavior; it's not until I am tracking the remote branch that I see the modifications. To be clear, this is not a modified branch. If I pull from develop, or reset, and open a Storyboard, there are these differences.

Comment: thats what when you open a storyboard or xib it gets modified. you can check this by doing the same process with none of your active tabs as xib or storyboard, just close them before checking it. You will see there is no difference there

Comment: @aman.sood: Yes, I see what you mean, now. I already know that the modification itself is the result of Xcode interpreting an XML Storyboard into IB. I'm also fairly certain that the source of the problem is different system versions/settings between team members. My problem is finding a workaround or fix for this behavior that will meet my team leader's standards. He doesn't want all of those modifications when we merge code, and doesn't want me taking the time to undo the modifications in a text editor.